# Como manter ícone alinhado a esquerda ao redimensionar página?

Tags: css

Possuo uma página que ao ser redimensionada a imagem do facebook fica quebrado e não estou conseguindo deixa-lo alinhado a esquerda junto ao campo da newsletter, já tentei diminuir o tamanho do input e não ficou legal, fiz isso:

```
#newsletter-form input#newsletter {
   float: left;
   width: 300px; /* ALTEREI DE 360 PARA 300 */
   margin-right: 10px;
   display: inline;
}
```

Além do input ficar menor ao redimensionar o imagem continuo quebrada.
A página pode ser vista aqui, sem a alteração: [Site em desenvolvimento](http://moveissaobento.com.br/msb/)

Comment: Percebi na sua página um css atrelado a imagem `#newsletter-wrap img`, que está com float: right; no caso é sua imagem do facebook (ícone), alterei ela para left, e ficou melhor mas não sei se é o resultado que você precisa.... Ou você também pode tirar o float; Diminua de 300px para 280px o input que já fica melhor também; Veja se é o resultado que você quer...

Comment: Olá @RafaelWithoeft, obrigado pela dica, a imagem agora ficou colada ao input e mesmo assim ainda está quebrada.

Comment: Quebrada em que sentido? Qual o resultado que você espera da página ao ser redimensionada? Assim talvez ficaria mais fácil de ajudar;

Comment: Digo, jogou a imagem para a linha de baixo, como posso dar um espaço entre o o botão  e a imagem?

Comment: Pode usar um padding-left de uns 15px para deixar um pouco mais longe, em caso de quebrar... caso não esteja usando bootstrap, acredito que teria que usar css medias queries: http://tableless.com.br/introducao-sobre-media-queries/ e assim adaptar o seu input para diferentes "medidas"

Comment: Você pode tirar o float e o display do #newsletter-wrap img que o efeito continuará o mesmo, só deixe o padding-left; e veja sobre medias queries para adaptar seu input a diferentes resoluções; ouu... você pode usar width: 70%, por exemplo; Faça um teste e veja o que melhor se adapta para você;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primeiramente remova os `display: inline` já que você esta usando `float: left`. Depois remova `width e height` do img e coloca no css para ficar melhor.

**Código**

```css
#newsletter-form input#newsletter {
    float: left;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    margin-right: 10px;
    width: 360px;
}
#newsletter-form input.button {
    float: left;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    margin-right: 3px;
}
#newsletter-wrap img {
    height: 29px;
    margin: 0;
    width: 29px;
}
```